# What is the representation for a number that is not quite one?

Tags: infinity, decimal-expansion

If: $$0.\overline{9999999} \equiv 1$$

Then how would you represent a value that is *infinitesimally* close to one, but not *quite* one?

i would have thought: $$1-\frac 1 \infty $$

But i would take that to be: $$0.\overline{9999999} = 1$$

Or do i have to subtract an infinitesimal amount from one?

$$ 1 - 0.\overline{000000}1$$

$$ 1 - 1 \times 10 ^{-\infty}$$

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_number#Definition

Comment: If $x$ is a real number, it's either $1$ or it isn't.  If it isn't, then $|1-x|$ is a real number greater than $0$, and that's how exactly far $x$ is from $1$.  Not an infinitesimal.  If you want a different answer, then you need to work outside the real numbers.

Comment: [What is so wrong with thinking of real numbers as infinite decimals?](https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/~wtg10/decimals.html)

Comment: @mjqxxxx What is the smallest value x can take satisfying `1-x < 1`?

Comment: @IanBoyd: There isn't one.  For any $x$ that satisfies $1-x < 1$, there is *always* a smaller $x$ (just divide by two!).

Comment: @jwodder But `1-x = 0` for small enough values of x?

Comment: @IanBoyd: $1-x = 0$ if & only if $x = 1$.  If you meant to ask whether $1 - (1-x) = 0$ for "small enough" values of $x$, note that $1 - (1-x) = x$, and $x$ equals zero (oddly enough) only when it *actually equals zero*.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The real numbers do not have any infinitesimals, so there is no need to represent such a number.  There are other fields that do allow them, such as the [hyperreal numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperreal_number) and the [surreal numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surreal_number) and they have ways of representing them.  They give up some of the properties of the reals that many find convenient, such as completeness.

Comment: Indeed, they give up the property of decimal representation, which pretty much all of us find convenient.

Comment: @Gerry, Well, they have Gonshor's sign expansions, so that a good portion of them have something very much like binary. All dots are binary points, not decimal points: "+"=1, "+-"=.1, "+-+"=.11, "+-++"=.111, "+-+++"=.1111, ... *However* "+-++++++..." refers to a well defined Surreal less than 1 but greater than all of 1/2, 3/4, 7/8,...